# Один иноязычный автор цитирует другого, - как подписать эпиграф?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

[Корнель Петер > Пути к раю. Комментарии к потерянной рукописи](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=207461&p=2)

...так, Петер Хандке видит в определенном геологическом пункте этой горы свой собственный центр:

> «В поисках связи я напал на еще один особенный след, по которому счел
>   своим долгом идти, хотя и не знал, куда он ведет и вообще ведет ли он
>   куда-либо. Все предшествующие месяцы каждый раз, когда я смотрел на
>   картины, на которых Сезанн запечатлел свою гору, я обнаруживал этот
>   след, пока он не стал для меня навязчивой идеей.
>
> Горный массив увиден с левой стороны, где он образует тройную
>   вершину с ее пластами и складками в геологическом разрезе. Я читал о
>   том, что другом юности Сезанна был геолог по имени Марион, который и
>   позднее часто сопровождал художника, когда тот работал па пленэре.
>   Когда я изучал карты горы и ее описания, мое воображение по какой-то
>   непонятной причине постоянно кружило вокруг одного и того же места:
>   это разлом между двумя различными породами. Он находится на дороге,
>   которая, плавно поднимаясь вверх, ведет с запада к самому гребню и по
>   сути дела представляет собой „точку", потому что линия гребня там
>   разрывается, когда одна порода вклинивается в другую. В природе
>   невооруженный глаз эту точку не различит, но на картинах художника она
>   появляется снова и снова более или менее темным пятном; даже в
>   карандашных набросках это вклинивание обозначено штрихами или хотя бы
>   очерчено мягким контуром».

Петер Корнель вполне подписывает цитату:

> Peter Handke. «Der Weg zum St. Victoire», 1980 (Петер Хандке. «Путь к
>   горе Сент-Виктуар»).

Далее. Мой автор берёт в качестве эпиграфа закавыченный выше фрагмент - и именно из Петера Корнеля. При этом хочет не умолчать и о первоисточнике - Петере Хандке.

Он тоже гуглибелен, но [там другой перевод](https://libking.ru/books/prose-/prose-contemporary/217197-17-peter-handke-uchenie-gory-sen-viktuar.html#book):

> В моих жадных поисках взаимосвязи я натолкнулся еще на один, особый
>   след, который я не мог позволить себе оставить без внимания, хотя мне
>   было неизвестно, куда он меня выведет и выведет ли вообще. В течение
>   всех этих месяцев я, рассматривая гору на картинах Сезанна, всякий раз
>   ловил себя на том, что этот обнаруженный мною «след» уже превратился
>   для меня в навязчивую идею.
>
> Ведь массив, если смотреть на него с западной стороны, откуда он
>   видится треуголкой, имеет, со всеми этими складками и слоями, вид
>   геологического разреза. Я где-то читал, что у Сезанна был друг юности,
>   геолог по имени Марион, вот он-то и сопровождал нередко художника,
>   когда тот отправлялся обследовать ландшафт в поисках мотива. Всякое
>   обращение к соответствующим картам и описаниям горы, которые я
>   принялся тщательно изучать, заканчивалось тем, что моя фантазия
>   непроизвольно и необъяснимо, но с поразительной настойчивостью
>   возвращалась к одной и той же точке: к месту излома, где сходятся два
>   слоя разных пород. Это место находится прямо на тропинке, довольно
>   спокойно поднимающейся вместе с линией гребня, за которым, собственно,
>   и начинается гряда, и представляет собою действительно всего-навсего
>   «точку», поскольку там, на стыке двух слоев, отчетливо выходящих на
>   поверхность, пролегает и разделяющая их кромка гребня. Простым
>   невооруженным глазом эту точку не увидеть, но на картинах художника
>   она все время повторяется в виде оттенения, иногда совсем легкого,
>   иногда чуть более плотного; даже на карандашных рисунках это небольшое
>   углубление отмечено штриховкой или же дано еле заметным контуром.

**ВОПРОС:**

подойдёт ли моё оформление эпиграфа (я с таким никогда не сталкивалась):

> «В поисках связи я напал на ещё один особенный след, по которому счёл
>   своим долгом идти, хотя и не знал, куда он ведёт и вообще ведёт ли он
>   куда-либо. Все предшествующие месяцы каждый раз, когда я смотрел на
>   картины, на которых Сезанн запечатлел свою гору, я обнаруживал этот
>   след, пока он не стал для меня навязчивой идеей.
>
> *Горный массив увиден с левой стороны, где он образует тройную вершину с её пластами и складками в геологическом разрезе. Я читал о том, что
>   другом юности Сезанна был геолог по имени Марион, который и позднее
>   часто сопровождал художника, когда тот работал па пленэре. Когда я
>   изучал карты горы и её описания, моё воображение по какой-то
>   непонятной причине постоянно кружило вокруг одного и того же места:
>   это разлом между двумя различными породами. Он находится на дороге,
>   которая, плавно поднимаясь вверх, ведёт с запада к самому гребню и по
>   сути дела представляет собой “точку”, потому что линия гребня там
>   разрывается, когда одна порода вклинивается в другую. В природе
>   невооружённый глаз эту точку не различит, но на картинах художника она
>   появляется снова и снова более или менее тёмным пятном; даже в
>   карандашных набросках это вклинивание обозначено штрихами или хотя бы
>   очерчено мягким контуром» (Петер Хандке. «Путь к горе Сент-Виктуар»).*
>
> Петер Корнель. Пути к раю. Комментарии к потерянной рукописи

Comment: Главное, чтобы не получился "перевод перевода" - нужен перевод непосредственно с языка цитируемого источника, а не с языка автора, приводящего цитату (если это другой язык).

Comment: У нас получился именно "перевод перевода": один автор немец, другой швед. И оба переведены на русский (разными переводчиками). Но вопрос-то *как быть?* Саша, глянь только на последнее жёлтенькое - мой вариант оформления, - годится?

Comment: Подписывать надо автором слов Петер Хандке и делать что‐то типа сноски или примечания,  что цитируется по... (указать источник).